# Is it possible in Silverlight to stream a live video screencast of the desktop?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, desktop, video-streaming, conferencing

I would like to develop a web conferencing system (or web classroom) as a graduation project using Silverlight similar to

[iVocalize](https://www.ivocalize.com/)

which is a java applete .

I don't know if what is possible for a java applete to perform on the PC is also possible for Silverlight, or is SL more restricted.

There are two functionalities (which are related i guess) that iVocalize provides which i would also like to include in my SL application, which are:

1. A participant may broadcast a live video stream of the desktop to other participants so that they will be able to follow all activities performed on the computer.
2. A participant may take a snapshot of the desktop

If the previous functionalities are not possible in SL than do you think that WPF may be used instead?

Thank you vey much.

Answer (score 1):

1. Actually, you can use Silverlight 4 Web cam features.
2. With Silverlight 4, you can develop full-trust Silverlight application that can capture the snapshot of user desktop.

Comment: So does this mean than I can stream videos of my desktop? Thanks.

Comment: actually, if u just want to share the desktop, it's better if you use other mature software (e.g. VNC) for that.. 

the easier way is that you can take your desktop from webcam and share that video with other... 

But i think you may not want to use WPF or SL for that. Why don't you just use the mature C# VNC library http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enSG354SG355&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23+vnc with winform or WPF ..

Answer (score 0):

Using Silverlight it is possible.. Have a look at this open source silverlight project. Its has desktop sharing as one of the module

http://silverlightvideochat.codeplex.com/